# Is there a difference between Europe/London and UTC in PHP?

Tags: php, time, timezone, utc

I know that UTC and GMT are effectively the same thing.

BST (British Standard Time) is GMT +- 1 hour depending on DST (Daylight Saving Time).

With that in mind, how is Europe/London interpreted in PHP? Is it basically UTC/GMT?

Comment: Isn't BST *British Summer Time* (not *British Standard Time*)? It *is* Daylight Saving Time. When not, *"[The United Kingdom uses Greenwich Mean Time or Western European Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_European_Time)* (the latter the the same as in Portugal, Ireland, Faroe Islands, Canary Islands, Madeira islands, North Eastern Greenland, and Iceland).

Comment: Also, *"[Meaning of British Standard Time in English: Greenwich Mean Time (now disused).](https://www.lexico.com/definition/british_standard_time)"*. However, there was also a BST with that difference, but all year round, for about 3 years, from 18 February 1968 to 31 October 1971. *"[The United Kingdom experimentally adopted Central European Time by maintaining Summer Time throughout the year from 1968 to 1971.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom#History)"*

Comment: Maybe BST as *British Standard Time* is from an old source?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> how is Europe/London interpreted in PHP? Is it basically UTC/GMT?

They are not the same (UTC/GMT has no daylight savings). As of this writing they are an hour apart:

```
$utc = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $utc->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output: 2013-06-03 15:37:08

$el = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $el->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //  output: 2013-06-03 16:37:08
```